# Android Tablet - Chrome/ Native Browser: Address Bar and Fixed Height (100%) Issue

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, native

I am trying to solve a height problem.

I have a fixed, fullscreen container that has a height of 100%.

I am having a few issues with it however.

When I open Chrome or the Native Android browser, the height is worked out along with the address bar. I can then scroll down an additional 60 or so pixels (even though the container has overflow: hidden). Once I have the address bar is hidden and the correct height is calculated.

This transition looks terrible.

I have read many solutions involving the following:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1)
```

This does not work. I tried it like this:

```
document.getElementById('fullscreen').scrollTo(0, 1);
```

This did not work either.

I am calling this within an open function.

The fullscreen element is shown when a button is clicked. Once the button is clicked the open function is initiated.

I have also tried adding a setTimeout to the scrollTo, but this does not change anything.

Are there any fullproof solutions to this? I am open to CSS or JS fixes.

**Code Example**

```
<style type="text/css">
  #fullscreen { 
    background: #000;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
</style>

<a id="open" href="#">Open</a>
<div id="fullscreen"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var open;

   open = function () {
     'use strict';
     var fullscreen = document.getElementById('fullscreen');

     fullscreen.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');

     setTimeout(function () { 
       fullscreen.scrollTo(0, 1);

     }, 100);

   };

   $sd('#open').on('click', function () {
      'use strict';
      open();
      return false;
   });
</script>
```

Cheers

Comment: The code has been added.

Comment: It is over a year ago, but I still face the same problem as you. Did you ever find any solutions? Google should take a lot at this...

Comment: I was unable to. I don't think there is a fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

...try this:

```
#fullscreen {
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add I have top: 0 and left: 0 on the element. I tried bottom: 0 and it did nothing to help.

Comment: well, it should. also remove height:100%;

Comment: Why would I remove the height of 100%? It is meant to be a responsive fixed element. Everything within it bases its height on this container.

Comment: ...and that's why you are using top:0 and bottom:0; Using these force the element to stretch using its heigher point at top=0 and its lower point at bottom=bottom.

Comment: That did nothing to solve the problem. A gap is still created by the address bar.